# Fit new model in statsmodel fails - RuntimeError

Tags: python, runtime-error, statsmodels

I have created one AR model using statsmodels . That has worked but when I tried to create new model I hav gotten RuntimeError :

> RuntimeError:  Model has been fit using maxlag=1, method=cmle,
> ic=None, trend=c. These cannot be changed in subsequent calls to
> `fit`. Instead, use a new instance of AR.

This is how I generated the first model:

```
model=AR(df['Pop'])
AR1fit=model.fit(maxlag=1)

...
AR1fit.predict(start=start,end=end)


#the 2nd model:
AR2fit=model.fit(maxlag=2)
>>>
RuntimeError: 
Model has been fit using maxlag=1, method=cmle, ic=None, trend=c. These
cannot be changed in subsequent calls to `fit`. Instead, use a new instance of
AR.
```

I haven't found any post about this specific error, my goal is to  fit the new model .

Comment: Is it working if you use a new instance:  `AR2fit = AR(df['Pop']).fit(maxlag=2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate a new model for the `AR(2)` and then call the `fit` method:

```
model2 = AR(df['Pop'])
AR2fit = model2.fit(maxlag=2)
```